# Custom Authentication OpenRasta

Tags: c#, authentication, restful-authentication, openrasta

Hi I´m building an application that has a token based authentication ex:

http://www.host.com/resource?token=589437534

I was going write an interceptor or something like that, but I imagine that there is something more elegant available that I just could´t find.

What is the best way yo implement this kind of authentication with OpenRasta ?

Answer (score 2):

From an http PoV you should really not roll your own token-based hidden non-standard authentication and should instead try to use one of the many standardized ways of doing http auth (basic or digest) or one of the many SAML/OpenId/OAuth ways of doign token-based.

If you go for the latter, then there's an extension point for http authentication you can find in [OpenRasta - Scott Littlewoods Basic Authentication working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127764/openrasta-scott-littlewoods-basic-authentication-working-example)